# Minecraft crashes before it can even generate a log?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

After having searched for a while, I am finally asking help.

**The problem:** As soon as I log into a world (no matter MP/SP), the game crashes and I get an error window saying something went wrong with Java.

Bigger problem, it turns out it *does not even generate a Minecraft crash report*. Is there a way of making it? This is the *Windows* error log: [link](http://codeshare.io/UjjFL)

I have tried reinstalling Minecraft (using new launcher), deleting everything, trying Optifine, updating software & drivers, changing Java arguments, changing Java version. Haven't found anything that worked.

#### Minecraft Specs:

- Version: 1.8.8
- Launcher: 1.6.48

#### PC Specs:

- **OS:** Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.17415)
- **CPU:** Intel Core i7-4710MQ Quad Core (2,5 GHz, 6Mb Cache, Turbo 3,5GHz)
- **RAM:** 8 GB (1x 8GB) 1600Mhz DDR3 memory (3 free slots)
- **HDD:** 240 GB SSD, ~140 free
- **Graphics:** NVIDIA Quadro K1100M 2GB

Comment: I'd recommend reading [this Meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question).  It should help you figure out what you need, and where it is.

Comment: @Frank In this case, Minecraft failed to write a crash log because it didn't get that far. (if it did, they would be in `crash-reports` in your `.minecraft` folder) Anyway, it seems like it's having a problem with `ig75icd64.dll` (the Intel graphics driver). Make sure that Java is running on your NVIDIA GPU instead of the on-board one and try updating your drivers.

Comment: @Unionhawk You were absolutely right! My drivers were updated, I checked that, now that I forced to use the nvidia one it works again all of a sudden. The weird thing being that it used to work before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minecraft is trying to run on the on-board Intel GPU, since it's having trouble with `ig75icd64.dll` (Addressed in [MC-32606](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-32606)). Make sure Java is set to run on the NVIDIA GPU instead of the integrated one. This will both increase overall performance, and should eliminate this JVM crash.

If this reoccurs, make sure your graphics drivers are up-to-date. If that still doesn't work, try disabling the VBOs video setting (noted in the bug tracker page as a potential fix).